# What is the cleanest way to get the average of each item list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List<Expenses>` in dart. It looks like this:

```
[
    {itemId: 1,
     quantity: 10.0
    },
    {itemId: 2,
     quantity: 14.0
    },
    {itemId: 2,
     quantity: 25.0
    },
    {itemId: 3,
     quantity: 3.0
    }

   ...
];
```

I would like to get the average of each itemId to obtain a List like this:

```
[
    {itemId: 1,
     quantity: 10.0
    },
    {itemId: 2,
     quantity: 19.5
    },
    {itemId: 3,
     quantity: 3.0
    }

   ...
];
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: use [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) top level function

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: `groupBy(data, (e) => e['itemId'])` - now iterate over returned map

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is the simplest but it works:

```dart
void main() {
  List data = [
    {"itemId": 1, "quantity": 10.0},
    {"itemId": 2, "quantity": 14.0},
    {"itemId": 2, "quantity": 25.0},
    {"itemId": 3, "quantity": 3.0}
  ];

  List formattedList(List list) {
    var obj = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (obj[list[i]["itemId"]] == null) {
        obj[list[i]["itemId"]] = {"count": 1, "quantity": list[i]["quantity"]};
      } else {
        obj[list[i]["itemId"]]["count"] += 1;
        obj[list[i]["itemId"]]["quantity"] += list[i]["quantity"];
      }
    }

    List sol = [];
    for (var key in obj.keys) {
      sol.add({"itemId": key, "quantity": obj[key]["quantity"] / obj[key]["count"]});
    }
    return sol;
  }

  print(formattedList(data));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way using Reduce and GroupBy?

Comment: :D Thank you. Me neither yet

Comment: You can use this code until Reduce and GroupBy methods click, but internal implementation looks the same, based on Map.

Comment: `var data = [ {'itemId': 1, 'quantity': 10.0}, {'itemId': 2, 'quantity': 14.0}, {'itemId': 2, 'quantity': 25.0}, {'itemId': 3, 'quantity': 3.0}, ];  var avg = []; groupBy(data, (e) => e['itemId']) .forEach((k, v) { final total = v.map((e) => e['quantity']).reduce((v, e) => v + e); avg.add({ 'itemId': k, 'quantity': total / v.length, }); }); print(avg);` @DavidL notice how `total` is computed